# Scheme pattern matching - Match cons pair components and the whole cons pair at the same time

Tags: pattern-matching, scheme, destructuring

How a cons pair components (`car` and `cdr`) and the whole cons pair can be pattern matched in scheme using `match-lambda`? I'm looking for a concise and elegant way of extracting the cons pair components and having a reference to the whole cons pair at the same time.

The question can be split into two questions

1. How cons pair components (`car` and `cdr`) can be pattern matched in scheme?
2. How the whole pattern matched expression with the matched components can be captured in a single reference using `match-lambda`? I know that the above can be done using `match` inside `lambda`.

I've tried with no luck the below

```lisp
(match-lambda
  [(car-component . cdr-component) ... use car-component and cdr-component])
```

Ideally I'm looking for something like

```lisp
(match-lambda
  [((car-component . cdr-component) as whole-pair) ... use car-component, cdr-component, and whole pair])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the matcher can match cons pairs at all then you need an `and` pattern:

```
(match-lambda
  [(and whole
        (cons a b))
   ;; whole, a, b bound here
   ...]
  ...)
```

will work using Racket's `match-lambda`.

It looks as though different implementations have different syntaxes for matching conses as opposed to proper lists, and it's not clear to me that, for instance, [Guile's](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) can, but they all seem to have `and`, meaning 'all the patterns must match, binding suitable identifiers'.

(I'd regard an implementation which doesn't let you match conses as a little unuseful personally, so I hope they all do.  But I'm not a Scheme person, really.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the up to the point response. It seems that Guile cannot match a cons pair, but the general mechanism you proposed fully satisfies my question.

Comment: @VolodymyrProkopyuk `match-lambda` isn't specified in Scheme standard, but [SRI-204 Wright-Cartwright-Shinn Pattern Matcher](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-204/srfi-204.html#match-lambda). It is optional for implementations to implement these, but it usually is a reference implementation you can use.  Guile [SRFI list](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI-Support.html) indicates they do not support SRFI-204 and thus `match-lambda`, if it exists, will be something unique for Guile that does not follow the standard.

Comment: @Sylwester, thank you for pointing me to the SRFI-204. I'm looking forward to use its extended capabilities once it goes to the fina state. The `match-lambda` is available and working in Guile. What I was not able to do in Guile is to destructure a cons pair. Do you know a way to destructure a cons pair in Guile's implementation of `match-lambda`?